# Webview with html to link location can only click hyperlink once

Tags: android, html, webview

I seem that, when I use my link location on my Android webview, it only allow me to click it once. Then when I go back to click it again, it doesn't lead me to where i link it already. But when i use 2 buttons, and click them alternately, it works that way, but i need to know how to be able to use only 1 button and link it, and able to keep using it. below is my coding for the html as well as webview.

```
    public class more extends Activity{
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getAssets();
            WebView web = new WebView(this);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/more123.html");
            setContentView(web);


    }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
                finish();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }


    }


    <html>
    <body>

    <p>
    <a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4.</a>
    </p>

    <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 3</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2><a name="C4">Chapter 4</a></h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 5</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 6</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 7</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 8</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 9</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 10</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 11</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 12</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 13</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 14</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 15</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 16</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter 17</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isClicked=false;
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(url.equals("ur desired url") && isClicked==false)
    {
    //HYPER LINK IS CLICKED FIRST TIME
    isClicked=true;
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }
    else
    {
    //DO NOTHING HYPER LINK IS ALREADY CLICKED

    }



            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your code might help;

```
private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```